# Как ставить курсор в конец строки при вводе и достижении лимита в div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

**Наработки:**

```js
var editable = document.getElementById('message_text');
 $('#message_text').on("keydown keyup", function(e) {
       if(editable.innerHTML.length > 20){
           editable.innerHTML = editable.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
  }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-text="Текст сообщения" tabindex="0" id="message_text" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Как при вводе и достижении лимита по символам, удалять лишний символ и оставить курсор на конце?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот так примерно

```js
var editable = document.getElementById('message_text');
var range;
var sel;

$('#message_text').on("keydown keyup", function(e) {

    if(editable.innerHTML.length > 20){
        editable.innerHTML = editable.innerHTML.substr(0, 20);
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(editable.firstChild, editable.innerHTML.length);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        editable.focus();
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-text="Текст сообщения" tabindex="0" id="message_text" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Comment: Хмм наткнулся на проблему, когда методом копировать\вставить вставляется больше дозволенного а удаляется по одному. Как тогда удалить не по одному а все за гранью 20 символов?

Comment: вместо .slice(0, -1) использовать .substr(0, 20)